# Inner Content control properties disappeared in word 2016

Tags: word-2016

I inserted a new content control into the document.
Bind the custom XML to content control.
Insert the rich text content control inside the content control which is bound with custom XML.
Open the "Properties" dialog, add Title, check/select the options of 'Content control cannot be deleted' and 'Content cannot be edited' boxes and click on 'OK'.
Save the document and close the document.
Again open the document.
Note that the "Properties" which have applied to child/inner rich text content control got disappeared or properties are removed.
Why properties are removed?